# Can you filter on Logger level in log4net

Tags: filter, log4net, logging

I am want to filter out messages that contain specified string. I used `log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter` but that applies to appenders only.

I'd like to filter that message on Logger level already. Something along these lines:

```
<logger name="MyLogger.WebServices">
    <level value="Debug" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="do not log me" />
        <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
    </filter>
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="debug" />
</logger>
```

Is it actually possible this way? Or is there a different way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Filters are for use with appenders only. If you need to filter out events for several appenders you can pre-filter using a forwardingappender. This way you avoid having to copy and paste the same filter on several appenders.

Your example would look like this:

```
<appender name="screeningAppender" type="log4net.Appenders.ForwardingAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
            <stringToMatch value="do not log me" />
            <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
    </filter>

    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="debug" />
</appender>

<logger name="MyLogger.WebServices">
    <level value="Debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="screeningAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: That's what I feared. Cheers!

Comment: I had thought to make a custom appender or derive from one that was environment aware (e.g. dev or production), but I like the idea of moving this to a filter to "give" all appenders that capability.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me.  I was using a LevelToMatch filter and it didn't forward.  Maybe it's because the filter was an acceptOnMatch = true with a denyAll following... don't know.

Comment: @Alex - are you still having problems getting this to work? If so, perhaps you could raise a question on it with your configuration included so we could have a look at it :)